# Persisting a report snapshot in database automatically

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I was wondering is there a way for me to generate an excel or PDF version of a report in code and persist that report in another SQL database?

Best regards

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback guys. Apologies for not providing the sufficient detail. The database system I am working with is SQL Server 2008 and obviously the reporting platform is Reporting Services.I will save the output in a row as a binary type or blob and after that point it does not matter anymore.  
However, where I get stuck is trying to find out if it is possible to generate an instance of a report against an existing rdl file by initiating this operation in .NET code and receive what would be the output (Excel, or PDF) as a return object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this. It was pretty basic.

The thing I am using is the report viewer component and I generate a binary stream of data that I will save in a field in the SQL database either as BLOB or varbinary (still need to verify this a little) Here is an example of the source:

```
        Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
        Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
        Dim mimeType As String = Nothing
        Dim encoding As String = Nothing
        Dim extension As String = Nothing
        Dim bytes As Byte()

        'This reads the report as a binary stream of data, could be Excel, PDF, etc
        bytes = ExportReportViewer.ServerReport.Render("Excel", _
          Nothing, mimeType, _
            encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying, but you could store your file as a BLOB or as a link to a physical file in a filesystem. So basically:

1) fetch the data you want
2) process it
3) save in another DB as blob/link.

If you give more details (which DBMS? Any framework? What language?) I think people here would provide more relevant answers.

Comment: I notice Tachi has tagged this as ssrs-2008, which may imply that SQLServer 2008 is the DBMS.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback guys. 

Apologies for not providing the sufficient detail. The database system I am working with is SQL Server 2008 and obviously the reporting platform is Reporting Services.

With regard to Kenji's comment, on a high level that is what I have in mind. I will save the output in a row as a binary type or blob and after that point it does not matter anymore.

Comment: However, where I get stuck is trying to find out if it is possible to generate an instance of a report against an existing rdl file by initiating this operation in .NET code and receive what would be the output (Excel, or PDF) as a return object?

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about .NET or Reporting Services. I hope you get a better answer from a Windows developer. =)